# Каковы алгоритмы одновременной работы администраторов в популярных CMS?

Tags: wordpress, битрикс, joomla, cms, drupal

Каковы алгоритмы одновременной работы администраторов в популярных CMS?
А именно, интересны:

- возможность авторизации двух человек с разными ip из-под одного логина;
- возможность одновременной редакции контента одной страницы двумя пользователями;
- возможность удаления страницы одним пользователем в тот  момент, когда ее редактирует другой;
- и т.п.

Кто с какими системами разбирался, какие варианты реализаций знает - подскажите. Очень интересно любое мнение.

Comment: Джумла - яркий пример))) там об этом просто не парились, творите что хотите и разбирайтесь по телефону, что за хрен с горы удалил категорию, в которую вы только что добавили 18 записей))

Comment: Что-то не верю...) Джумла, конечно, та еще гадость, но что-то там было с множеством авторизованных админов...

Comment: Ну можно и настроить блокировку - тогда будете по телефону выянять, что за хрен с горы не снял блокировку и на главной висит вчерашняя инфа, а отредактировать ее можно только поюзав утилиту "сброс блокировки" =)

Именно эта часть (как, впрочем, многие другие) плохо продумана и еще хуже реализована. *3 года работы с джумлой.

Comment: больная тема :)

Answer (score 2):

Из всего обследованно более всего нравится реализация в cms MODx...

Мультиавторизация - разрешена. Но стоит правильная защита от подбора пароля (считает ошибки подряд) хотя и задалбывает - стоит увеличивать квоту..

Пока идет редактированние вводится блок на страницу. При улете сессии блоки можно снимать, но минус в том что только все сразу. Редактировать одно и тоже нельзя. Удалить редактируемое - нельзя.

Есть возможность накладывать групповые политика на ресурсы и таким образом закрывать часть ресурсов от изменения и удаления. Админ, естественно может всё.

Удаление идет в два такта - пометка на удалении и физическое удаление (естественно права настраиваются). Пометка закрывает ресурс от видимости снаружи, но может быть безболезненно снята.

И всё это даже условно-шустро работает.

Answer (score 0):

Битрикс.

1. Количество одновременных авторизаций с одним логином не ограничивается. Настраивается только "Максимальное количество компьютеров, на которых может быть одновременно запомнена авторизация"
2. Редактировать/удалять дает одновременно - все на откуп организации работы внутри команды работающей по сайту. В прочем, при необходимости, легко реализуемо.
3. Единственное редактирование заказа (через админку). Система предупреждает, что в данный момент заказ открыт на редактирование еще кем то. И есть кнопка "Снять блокировку"

Вообще все же "под одним логином" это плохая практика не зависимо от CMS. Гораздо правильнее каждому иметь свой аккаунт, тогда будет гибкость в настройках прав. И, как показывает практика, в случае ЧП выстреливающих раз  в пятилетку может помочь в разборе полетов.